# Can there be a problem if I use $m=\tan(x)$ for slope of a line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently I started watching Dr.Herbert Gross's videos on calculus. In the first lecture, he says that if we use $m=\tan(x)$ for the slope of a line it may be incorrect provided the scales are different for horizontal and vertical axes but using two points for slope there would not be any problem. I don't understand why scaling should be a problem.

Comment: What does it mean 'using two points for slope'?

Comment: By two points you mean $m=\frac {y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$???

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Make a difference between the slope of a line in the absolute, and the slope of the line *as plotted*.

In the first case,

$$m_1=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$ where $m$ is the $m$ in $y=mx+p$.

In the second case, the scaling of the axis will matter. Assuming $X$ mm per unit for the abscissas and $Y$ mm per unit on the ordinates,

$$m_2=\tan\theta=\frac{Y\Delta y}{X\Delta x}=\frac YXm_1$$ where $\theta$ is the angle "on paper".

In case of isotropic scaling, both slopes are equal.

Answer (score 0):

If the scales are different the angle $\theta $ doesn't give the correct value for $m=\tan \theta$.

For example, let consider the line through the points $O=(0,0)$ and $P=(1,1)$, if we scale the horizontal axis with a factor $2$ the tangent of the angle we read

$$\tan \theta = \frac{1}{2}$$

is different from that we can evaluate by coordinates

$$m=\tan \theta=\frac{1-0}{1-0}=1$$

which is the correct one to be considered to evaluate the slope of the line.